# Running a core php project from apache instead of php -S localhost:4000

Tags: php, apache, lamp

I'm trying to run a php project using apache configurations in LAMP but its not working*, whereas when I run it as `php -S locahost:4000` its working really great.
Here is the link to the project if you need some info about the files or working of it [Project](https://github.com/Rishabh04-02/Elective-manager)

Here is my apache configuration -

```
<VirtualHost localhost:4000>
ServerAdmin root@localhost
ServerName localhost
ServerAlias localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/dir

<Directory "/var/www/html/dir">
AllowOverride None
Options None
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

*not working means - when running it through apache i can only access the index page and when going to some other page of the project like `localhost:4000/about` It shows `The requested URL /department was not found on this server.` ie. Error 404.

Comment: Please explain what "not working" means, and use your browser dev tools to inspect the http response received.

Comment: "not working" means when running it through apache i can only access the index page and when going to some other page of the project like ``localhost:4000/about`` It shows ``The requested URL /department was not found on this server.``

Comment: Surely your not using localhost:4000 when on the production server.  You are putting the servers name in there.

Comment: @NigelRen Even after removing the server name and alias, its not working.

Comment: I'm assuming you fixed it as it seems to work as far as I can test it.

Comment: @NigelRen I havn't fixed it yet, but i guess I got to know the root of problem. I think I need to redirect all requests to ``index.php`` page using ``.htaccess`` file

Comment: @NigelRen Its working now, actually the ``a2enmod rewrite`` wasn't enabled on my apache server.

Comment: Glad to hear you've solved the problem.  There are a lot of parts to some problems and it's difficult to see where the issue is at times.

Comment: Yaa you are right, also I've updated the .htaccess file of project.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you expect "index.php" to receive all requests.
Now, Apache is trying to find "about" directory and "department" directory.
In order for Apache to run index.php on any URL, we need to use the Rewrite rule.

Although I have not verified it in detail, I guess it will work with the following rules.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /index.php
```

Comment: You're right that I expect index.php to receive all requests.
The solution you've provided is not solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It now working after enabling `a2enmod rewrite` from apache and updating the contents of `.htaccess` file as follows

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```